# value error in csvSchema 1.1 in python

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I am using [CSV Schema package in Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CsvSchema/1.1.0) and am validating string columns with a number of enlisted values. The problem is that the package gives the error of `no permissible values found` even though they are there. I double checked.

Anyone with any idea?

Code snipped where I define the rules :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# wrapper to work with csv files in python 
import codecs, ucsv as csv, unicodedata, sys, os
# opening an output file with write access, change to rw+ if working with linux
fo = open("C:/Users/Romi/Desktop/Level1Test/result.txt", "r+") 
# Open the feeds here, use os.walk for running through directory.
from csv_schema.structure.base import BaseCsvStructure
from csv_schema.columns import (
  IntColumn,
  DecimalColumn,
  StringColumn,
)

class TestCsvStructure(BaseCsvStructure):
  a = StringColumn(blank = True, min_length = 0, max_length = 12345,)
  b = StringColumn(blank = True, min_length = 0, max_length = 12345,)
  c = StringColumn(blank = True, min_length = 0, max_length = 12345, permissible_values = ["Null","Male","Female","Unknown"])
  d = StringColumn(blank = True, min_length = 0, max_length = 12345,permissible_values = ["No","Yes"])
  e = StringColumn(blank = True, min_length = 0, max_length = 12345,permissible_values = ["Inactive", "Active"])
```

The result/error that I get is:

> False,  u'Line 309, column 0: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 1: The value is not one of the acceptable',  .....

From result.txt:

```
309 line : [u'Line 309, column 2: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 3: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 4: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 5: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 6: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 7: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 8: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 9: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 10: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 11: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 12: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 13: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 14: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 15: The value is not one of the acceptable', u'Line 309, column 16: 
    ...
    False
```

It shows column 47 and 48 don't have acceptable values but they clearly do. In permissible values, I pasted "[u'value']" and it recognizes the others except for these two.

Comment: Please include a code snippet that demonstrates the problem, complete with a relevant piece of input data. (Unfortunately, our entire cadre of telepaths is on a permanent vacation.)

Comment: Nice one :D . Edited, please check 9000

Comment: Any chance to see line 309 from results.txt, or, better yet, lines 308-310?